# How to run loop in JSON Template

Tags: json, templates, loops, conditional-statements

In my application i'm using JSON Template for displaying content. I'm using conditional statements inside Template

```
{{#if document_id_1}} \
{{filename_1 }}
{{document_size_1}}
{{document_type_1}}
{{/if}}\ 
{{#if document_id_2}} \
{{filename_2 }}
{{document_size_2}}
{{document_type_2}}
{{/if}}\ 
 ................
```

i need to run loop (for or while) on this to avoid mentioning more if conditions in my code.

How can i run loop inside JSON Template???

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Mustache and assuming all of the documents looks the same and assuming this structure

```
{
  documents: [
    { filename: 'document_1', ... },
  ]
}

{{#documents}}
  {{ filename }}
  //other properties below
{{/documents}}
```

Comment: [
    { filename: 'document_1', ... },
] This is my json array structure. If i change the json array structure as you shown, json data not displaying...

Comment: Could you post some sample data?